# NLP in a Survey Table

Tags: r, powerbi

everyone. I'm with a table like this one, with more columns that are alike the "Opinion about Power Plant". Here's the problem, I'd like to see the most comum words in each column. How can I do it in R or PowerBI?
[image: Example analogue to my table]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Key Phrase Extraction and a Word Cloud visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/key-phrase-extraction/tutorials/integrate-power-bi).